# Jenkins master/slave with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-workflow

Right now we have Jenkins up and running on a single VM. It fetches the code from Github, builds and runs all Unit- and E2E Tests.

This takes 3+ hours.

The thing is, we have some integration tests that restore a test database. There are a lot of tests so it takes a long time.

We want to speed this up significantly.

So I created a Template Slave VM on Azure. It has Visual Studio, IIS, SQL Express, Git and everything else we would need for a deployment.

I can now clone this template to 5-6 identical slaves. Each will be instructed by the Jenkins master to build, deploy and test a chunk (suites) of the codebase.

Is this really the best infrastructure for this? It's a LOT of work setting this up. I have trouble finding good reading material on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to something called not only Continuous Integration, but more [Release Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/release/getting-started/understand-rm). Microsoft has the development platform [Visual Studio Team Service](http://visualstudio.com)s that can be used in [integration with Jenkins mode](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/integrate/service-hooks/jenkins-and-vso-vs) or/and you can create the build definition and release management definition and automate that.
Sure, it will involve some work (maybe a lot) but using VSTS + Azure (as they are tightly integrated) you can automate it for a future use.